# Prevent function bound to element's parent from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list where, when the user clicks on it a list item containing an input and a anchor tag gets appended.

Then when the user clicks the anchor, i want to perform a function. However, currently the       function bound to the unordered list fires before the anchor's function.

Example:

```
$('ul').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('this always fires first even when i only click the <a/>');
    // function to create the list item containing the input and link
  });

$(document).on('click', 'input, a', function(e){
    console.log('this fires second');
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation(); // doesnt seem to do anything, the ul's function still fires
  });
```

I know i can prevent the ul's function from firing by using the .off method but that means i would have to unbind and rebind every time.

Is there a better way to do this, or should i go with the .off method?

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: One is using event delegation and the other is not. Change both to use event delegation and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe delegating the `input, a` clicks to the document is the culprit; When it reaches that node, the event on the `ul` has already been fired. Try delegating the second event from the `ul` itself, and maybe use `stopImmediatePropagation()`.

An example on JSfiddle would help, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than registering the event against the `document` try adding it directly to the `ul` element. Like this:

```
$('ul').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('this always fires first even when i only click the <a/>');
    // will not be fired
});

$('ul').on('click', 'input, a', function (e) {
    console.log('this fires first!');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // now works
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/NPHF7/)